# Stop New Page After when parent group changes

Tags: group-by, pagination, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

In Crystal Reports, Group 1 is currency and Group 2 is GL Account. I want a new page after each GL Account but at the end of Group 1, I want the Group 1 footer to display on the last GL Account page instead of going to the next page. Setting New Page After on the Group 2 footer section works but I need a condition so a new page is not added when the Group 1 footer prints as the next section.

Group 1 Header: CAD  (New Page After - X-2: Not on first page)
GL Acct 1 *(New Page After)*
<NEW PAGE>
GL Acct 2
<NEW PAGE>
GL Acct 3  (Stop New Page After)
GROUP 1 Footer: CAD
<NEW PAGE>
GROUP 2 Header: US... etc

I tried New Page Before on the Group 2 header (except on the first page) but I need the Group 1 header to print on the same page as the first Group 2 record later on in the report.

Answer (score 0):

"when the Group 1 footer prints as the next section" could be translated into a formula like this:

`If {Group 1 field - probably currency} <> Next({Group 1 field - probably currency}) Then True Else False`